# Change chef-server settings port

Tags: chef-infra

I have chef-server installed, and I wanted to run this on different port.
so i changed port in  default.rb file. 
Now chef-server is running on different port but when I am trying to access it via browser it redirects to default URL, which says connection refused, because it is not running on default port.

what did i miss?

Please find the nginx section of the file.

```
default['private_chef']['nginx']['enable'] = true
default['private_chef']['nginx']['ha'] = false
default['private_chef']['nginx']['dir'] = "/var/opt/opscode/nginx"
default['private_chef']['nginx']['log_directory'] = "/var/log/opscode/nginx"
default['private_chef']['nginx']['log_rotation']['file_maxbytes'] = 104857600
default['private_chef']['nginx']['log_rotation']['num_to_keep'] = 10
default['private_chef']['nginx']['log_x_forwarded_for'] = false
default['private_chef']['nginx']['ssl_port'] = 8082
default['private_chef']['nginx']['enable_non_ssl'] = false
default['private_chef']['nginx']['non_ssl_port'] = 8083
default['private_chef']['nginx']['x_forwarded_proto'] = 'https'
default['private_chef']['nginx']['server_name'] = node['fqdn']
default['private_chef']['nginx']['url'] = "https://#{node['fqdn']}:8082/"
default['private_chef']['nginx']['proxy_connect_timeout'] = 1
```

Comment: Please include your `chef-server.rb` content. I will state for the record that Chef Server is intended to be an appliance, using custom ports usually implies you are running it on a machine that is doing other stuff, and this is generally not a great idea unless you really know deep down how Chef Server works.

Comment: Actually i did not find the default.rb so i changed in /opt/opscode/embedded/cookbooks/private-chef/attributes/default.rb

Comment: content of the file added in question

Comment: What version of chef server are you running?

Comment: chef server 12 privet-chef

Comment: Something sounds suspicious... "Private chef" refers to an older enterprise version of Chef 10. The documentation on the chef server configuration is located here: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server.html. Could you read this and compare to what you have? Finally don't forget to run the command "chef-server-ctl reconfigure" whenever you make a change to the chef server configuration. For more detail see: https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_server.html#reconfigure

Comment: I dont know i could not find the chef-server.rb any where. and i did run chef-server-ctl reconfigure

Comment: DO NOT modify chef internal cookbooks, at next update your change are lost. The `chef-server.rb` file is the way to tweak the server, as said in the documentation link of the file @MarkO'Connor gave just above the file may not exist and you have to create it.